# Google BigQuery API doesn't work with http post request

Tags: http-post, google-bigquery

I have written an http post request in Java to access Bigquery Data. The following is my code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
public class Post {

    static String url =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project-ID>/queries?key=<API Broweser key>";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       //Instantiate an HttpClient
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

       //Instantiate a GET HTTP method
       PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
       method.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
               "application/json");
       method.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
               URLEncoder.encode("Bearer <authorization-token>","UTF-8"));

       //Define name-value pairs to set into the QueryString
       NameValuePair nvp1= new NameValuePair("query","select * from <TableName> limit 10");

       method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[]{nvp1});

       try{
           int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

           System.out.println("Status Code = "+statusCode);
           System.out.println("QueryString>>> "+method.getQueryString());
           System.out.println("Status Text>>>"
                 +HttpStatus.getStatusText(statusCode));

           //Get data as a String
           System.out.println(method.getResponseBodyAsString());

           //OR as a byte array
           byte [] res  = method.getResponseBody();

           //write to file
           FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("donepage.html");
           fos.write(res);

           //release connection
           method.releaseConnection();
       }
       catch(IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Unauthorized
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Note that I am able to access data through the BigQuery command line tool using the same authorization token. I have generated the authorization token using the following:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&
response_type=code&
client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

This follows the instructions at: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the guts of the authorization headers, but I'm not sure you're passing the OAuth token correctly. When you run the bq client, it turns the OAUth2 refresh token into an access token and passes that to the service. If you pass the raw refresh token, this is not acceptable for api access without turning it into a short-lived access token, as far as I know.

Is there a reason you don't want to use the BigQuery java client? (javadoc for the query call [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Jobs.Query.html), the bigquery docs for query with java samples are [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data). )

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get a credential with a service account in Java:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
    .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
    .setServiceAccountId(properties.getProperty("SERVICE_ACCOUNT"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"}))
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(properties.getProperty("P12_KEY")))
    .build();
```

With that, you can build a BigQuery service object:

```
BigQuery bigquery = Bigquery.Builder(
   new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName(
    "BigQuery-Service-Accounts/0.1").setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

With the service object, you can run your typical jobs:

```
bigquery.jobs().query(...)
```

Is there any reason you want to manually do the POST request?